# Gcm push notification not receiving

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I had a problem with push notification GCM in Android, the device is registered very well, I get the token, but when I send the notification using gradle command-

.\gradlew.bat run -Pmsg=""

I get this- 
{"message_id":5514585301987612462}
Check your device/emulator for notification or logcat for confirmation of the receipt of the GCM message.
I am not receiving the message neither in the emulator nor in the logcat.

GcmSender.java

```
package gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmsender;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class GcmSender {

    public static final String API_KEY = "AIzaSyA9eC36JEy5JcbdtfU6zW5IhmJrkqioT7o";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length < 1 || args.length > 2 || args[0] == null) {
            System.err.println("usage: ./gradlew run -Pmsg=\"MESSAGE\" [-Pto=\"DEVICE_TOKEN\"]");
            System.err.println("");
            System.err.println("Specify a test message to broadcast via GCM. If a device's GCM registration token is\n" +
                    "specified, the message will only be sent to that device. Otherwise, the message \n" +
                    "will be sent to all devices subscribed to the \"global\" topic.");
            System.err.println("");
            System.err.println("Example (Broadcast):\n" +
                    "On Windows:   .\\gradlew.bat run -Pmsg=\"<Your_Message>\"\n" +
                    "On Linux/Mac: ./gradlew run -Pmsg=\"<Your_Message>\"");
            System.err.println("");
            System.err.println("Example (Unicast):\n" +
                    "On Windows:   .\\gradlew.bat run -Pmsg=\"<Your_Message>\" -Pto=\"<Your_Token>\"\n" +
                    "On Linux/Mac: ./gradlew run -Pmsg=\"<Your_Message>\" -Pto=\"<Your_Token>\"");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        try {
            // Prepare JSON containing the GCM message content. What to send and where to send.
            JSONObject jGcmData = new JSONObject();
            JSONObject jData = new JSONObject();
            jData.put("message", args[0].trim());
            // Where to send GCM message.
            if (args.length > 1 && args[1] != null) {
                jGcmData.put("to", args[1].trim());
            } else {
                jGcmData.put("to", "/topics/global");
            }
            // What to send in GCM message.
            jGcmData.put("data", jData);

            // Create connection to send GCM Message request.
            URL url = new URL("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key=" + API_KEY);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            // Send GCM message content.
            OutputStream outputStream = conn.getOutputStream();
            outputStream.write(jGcmData.toString().getBytes());

            // Read GCM response.
            InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
            String resp = IOUtils.toString(inputStream);
            System.out.println(resp);
            System.out.println("Check your device/emulator for notification or logcat for " +
                    "confirmation of the receipt of the GCM message.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to send GCM message.");
            System.out.println("Please ensure that API_KEY has been replaced by the server " +
                    "API key, and that the device's registration token is correct (if specified).");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

And the RegistrationIntentService.java

```
package gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmPubSub;
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;
import com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID;

import java.io.IOException;

public class RegistrationIntentService extends IntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "RegIntentService";
    private static final String[] TOPICS = {"global"};

    public RegistrationIntentService() {
        super(TAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        try {

            InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
            String token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId),
                    GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);

            Log.i(TAG, "GCM Registration Token: " + token);


            sendRegistrationToServer(token);


            subscribeTopics(token);


            sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(QuickstartPreferences.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, true).apply();
            // [END register_for_gcm]
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Failed to complete token refresh", e);
            sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(QuickstartPreferences.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, false).apply();
        }

        Intent registrationComplete = new Intent(QuickstartPreferences.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(registrationComplete);
    }


    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        // Add custom implementation, as needed.
    }


    private void subscribeTopics(String token) throws IOException {
        GcmPubSub pubSub = GcmPubSub.getInstance(this);
        for (String topic : TOPICS) {
            pubSub.subscribe(token, "/topics/" + topic, null);
        }
    }


}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private BroadcastReceiver mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver;
    private ProgressBar mRegistrationProgressBar;
    private TextView mInformationTextView;
    private boolean isReceiverRegistered;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mRegistrationProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.registrationProgressBar);
        mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                mRegistrationProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =
                        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
                boolean sentToken = sharedPreferences
                        .getBoolean(QuickstartPreferences.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, false);
                if (sentToken) {
                    mInformationTextView.setText(getString(R.string.gcm_send_message));
                } else {
                    mInformationTextView.setText(getString(R.string.token_error_message));
                }
            }
        };
        mInformationTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.informationTextView);

        // Registering BroadcastReceiver
        registerReceiver();

        if (checkPlayServices()) {
            // Start IntentService to register this application with GCM.
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegistrationIntentService.class);
            startService(intent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver);
        isReceiverRegistered = false;
        super.onPause();
    }

    private void registerReceiver(){
        if(!isReceiverRegistered) {
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver,
                    new IntentFilter(QuickstartPreferences.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE));
            isReceiverRegistered = true;
        }
    }

    private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        int resultCode = apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (apiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(resultCode)) {
                apiAvailability.getErrorDialog(this, resultCode, PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST)
                        .show();
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "This device is not supported.");
                finish();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

MyGcmListenerService.java

```
package gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService;

public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyGcmListenerService";


    // [START receive_message]
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
        String message = data.getString("message");
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + from);
        Log.d(TAG, "Message: " + message);

        if (from.startsWith("/topics/")) {
            // message received from some topic.
        } else {
            // normal downstream message.
        }



        sendNotification(message);

    }



    private void sendNotification(String message) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
                .setContentTitle("GCM Message")
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

MyInstanceIDListenerService.java

```
package gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID;
import com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceIDListenerService;

public class MyInstanceIDListenerService extends InstanceIDListenerService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyInstanceIDLS";


    // [START refresh_token]
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegistrationIntentService.class);
        startService(intent);
    }
    // [END refresh_token]
}
```

QuickstartPreferences.java
package gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart;

```
public class QuickstartPreferences {

    public static final String SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER = "sentTokenToServer";
    public static final String REGISTRATION_COMPLETE = "registrationComplete";

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart" >

    <!-- [START gcm_permission] -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <!-- [END gcm_permission] -->

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- [START gcm_receiver] -->
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <!-- [END gcm_receiver] -->

        <!-- [START gcm_listener] -->
        <service
            android:name="gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart.MyGcmListenerService"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <!-- [END gcm_listener] -->
        <!-- [START instanceId_listener] -->
        <service
            android:name="gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart.MyInstanceIDListenerService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <!-- [END instanceId_listener] -->
        <service
            android:name="gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart.RegistrationIntentService"
            android:exported="false">
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Have you declared the Services in your manifest file ? Can you post your manifest file ?

Comment: Have you added GCMListner to your manifest?

Comment: Yeah I have added them.

Comment: Seems like you are missing these permissions  `<permission
        android:name="gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="cgcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart.C2D_MESSAGE" />`

Comment: It is now showing an exception like this-java.net.UnknownHostException: android.googleapis.com
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:668)
        at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173)

Comment: I think the exception is being thrown because it couldn't reach the url. Do I have to do any other thing, add any permission etc, so that it could reach that.

Answer (score 0):

Please check with [This](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/02/android-push-notifications-using-gcm-php-mysql-realtime-chat-app-part-3) link and cross check your code

Comment: Yeah I've checked it but it is displaying the same message as I had stated above.